# Connecting to remote server by ssh using ksh

Tags: ssh, ksh

I am trying to connect to a remote server through ssh.

$ssh "username"@host "command"
which prompts for password which can be done in  interactive systems.But I want to automate this by passing the password as argument instead of  typing interactively.
I am using ksh shell and I can't use expect is there any ksh specific solution to connect to remote server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set up authentication keys so that you don't need passwords. See `man ssh-keygen` for full details.